# Azure Vmrole WCF services unable to connect

Tags: wcf, azure, portforwarding, azure-vm-role

We've been experimenting with an online application hosted in a virtual machine (vmrole) on windows azure.

We are able to connect to the web portal of the application (http) but we are **not able** to connect to the wcf services using port 5001

We tried with firewalls down
We have enabled the port 5001 in/out
We did a port forwarding check and the port is open for external use.
The 5001 port is clearly listed as an endpoint.
Both the dns name and the ip fail to work, so it is not a dns problem.

On the localhost (using remote desktop) we can connect without a hitch.
On the wireshark sniffing there is no sign of a connection through the 5001 of any sorts.

Any advice on this topic would be appreciated
Tx

Comment: I moved the wcf services to same port as the portal (80). Now it works, it's probably a firewall restriction of my ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the VM Role project to have an external HTTP endpoint on port 5001.  You can do this either in the config files directly or through the project properties in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the VM Role project to have an external HTTP endpoint on port 5001. You can do this either in the config files directly or through the project properties in Visual Studio.

Sounds exactly like:

The 5001 port is clearly listed as an endpoint.